# is there a better way to get the basepath within the application module class (zend framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Module
{
     public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
     {
        $serviceLocator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceLocator->get('ViewHelperManager');
        $renderer = $viewHelperManager->getRenderer();
        $basePath = $renderer->basePath();
        // or $basePath = $renderer->basePath('en'); (passing string)
      }
 }
```

Is there a better way to achieve getting the base path? Also take in note i need the ability to pass a concatenated path (not required) (`$renderer->basePath('someurlpath')`)

Answer (score 1):

To get the base directory or the "Current Working Directory" you should use the PHP function: [`get_cwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) as ZF2 sets up the working directory within your `public/index.php`. See the ZF2 skeleton application: [`index.php`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php)

```php
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

So within your code you can do something like:

```
$myPath = get_cwd() . "/public/folder";
```